# iOS - How to know what triggered application() function?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a function that gets triggered, but I am unable to figure out what did make the app enter this state :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification) {
 /* bla bla */
}
```

What is the way to debug / figure this out ?

Comment: you mean adding breakpoints?

Comment: Because a notification was received?

Comment: You're obviously posting a local notification somewhere in your code. You often can't use breakpoints, because it can be something that was scheduled earlier. But you know the source is something your app posted. If you're saying you're posting this particular notification from multiple places/times and you'd like to know where, then you should populate the `userInfo` dictionary with enough information so you can diagnose which notification you're handling.

Comment: Thanks Rob, that was it : )